# Problems with If/Elseif. Code only executes first statement

Tags: php, if-statement

My code only executes the if statement, but does not continue to execute the else part. Ive tried each statement individually and they work fine. But, when I put them together, only the first statement is executed. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried this:

```
function body_google_webfonts() {
    if( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Handlee") :
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
    elseif ( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Kreon") :
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
    endif;
}
```

and this:

```
function body_google_webfonts() {
    if( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Handlee") :
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
    endif;
    if ( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Kreon") :
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
    endif;
}
```

and this:

```
function body_google_webfonts() {
    if( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Handlee") {
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
    }
    if ( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Kreon") {
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
    }
}
```

and I've tried this:

```
function body_google_webfonts() {
    if( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Handlee") {
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
  } else if ( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Kreon") {
        wp_register_style('body-google-webfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'body-google-webfonts');
  }
}
```

Comment: wow use double == note one =

Comment: I swear, there are a million of these questions here! **==** and **=**.

Comment: When you code 12 hours a day, it's SO easy to miss the littlest things. My brain needs a vacation :P Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is: you are not comparing two things, you are making the variable settings equal to "Handlee". 
This operation will always return true, so just the first if will be executed.

To solve this, use the correct sentence:

```
$settings['font_type_body'] == "Handlee"
```

With double "=".

@Jessica, a very good programation practice, to avoid this simple error, is always put your variable at right side of the comparation. Something like this:

```
int a = 0; 
if 0 == a
```

You can use it for others languages. It's good cause, if you try to do

```
If 0 = a
```

it's easy to find your problem in debug mode.

Answer (score 4):

You assigning a value to a variable instead of comparing it. That will always result in the statement being true.

```
if( $settings['font_type_body'] = "Handlee") :
```

should be

```
if( $settings['font_type_body'] == "Handlee") :
```

or

```
if( $settings['font_type_body'] === "Handlee") :
```

Comment: John I think one comment is enough!

Comment: My goodness. Thanks! I feel like an idiot for not catching that. Too bad, debug mode doesn't catch things like this, ha!